# Can I somehow create a list of typeparameters?

Tags: java, enums, type-parameter

I have a "Spawner" Class which has a Indefinite Timeline. Every now and then i want a "Wave" ob Objects to spawn which all inherit from my abstract "Sprite" Class. I thought about predefining some formations in Lists like

> X X M M H M M X X

where X is nothing, M is a Meteor and H is some kind of Health gain.

```
class Wave extends LinkedList<Sprite>
{
    public Wave(Sprite... wave) {
        for (Sprite sp : wave) {
            add(sp);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it than just using different integers and a check for each?

I also thought about a Enum but dont see a use except using its ordinary for the check.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `addAll` takes a `Collection`, not an array. `addAll(Arrays.asList(wave))`

Comment: thanks, i thought i once used addAll in a similar case

Comment: Do you have a need to know about the actual type of each element in the list, after they have been added? If there is no need to know, then @Michael's answer will work, I think. If you need to know the actual type, then your original integer based idea seems good. Enums have a limitation of not being dynamic - works well with limited and known values only. Then we have the instanceof check, which is not a great one again and has the same limitation as enums.

Comment: yes i need to know - they all have different behavior when colliding with the player, thanks!  i will try that then

Answer (score 0):

The [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern), perhaps?

Here's a simple example:

```
interface Sprite{
    void render();
}

class NullSprite implements Sprite {
    public void render() {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}

class MeteorSprite implements Sprite {
    @Override
    public void render() {
        System.out.print("M");
    }
}

class Wave extends LinkedList<Sprite> implements Sprite {
    public Wave(Sprite... wave) {
        addAll(Arrays.asList(wave));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        forEach(Sprite::render);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Wave(new NullSprite(), new MeteorSprite(), new NullSprite(), new MeteorSprite()).render();
    }
}
```

Prints

```
<space>M<space>M
```

I also used the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) here, so a `Wave` is actually a `Sprite`, consisting of a collection of other `Sprite`s. Might be useful too.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i want to have multiple formations. i dont want to create a method for each, or did i misunderstand your intention?